# My component isn't updating, am I mutating the state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have a container component that connects to the state which I made with immutable.js. When I update the state, my redux inspector tells me that the state is updated, but my component doesn't get the new updates and doesn't re-render.

My container component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { setCategoryActive } from '../actions'
import Category from '../components/Category'

class MenuList extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.categories = this.props.categories
    this.subreddits = this.props.subreddits
    this.allCategories = this.categories.get("allCategories")
    this.byName = this.categories.get("byName")
  }

  printSubreddits(category) {
    const subreddits = this.byName.get(category)
    const subredditsByName = subreddits.get("subredditsByName")

    const list = subredditsByName.map((subreddit, i) => {
      return <p className="swag" key={i}>{subreddit}</p>
    })

    return list
  }

  isCategoryActive(category) {
    const cat = this.byName.get(category)
    return cat.get("active")
  }

  printCategory(category, i) {
    console.log(this.isCategoryActive(category))
    return (
      <div className="category-container" key={i}>
        <Category name={category}
          active={this.isCategoryActive(category)}
          setActive={this.props.setCategoryActive.bind(this, category)} />
        {this.isCategoryActive(category) ? this.printSubreddits(category) : null}
      </div>
    )
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.allCategories.map((category, i) => {
          const x = this.printCategory(category, i)
          return x
        }, this)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  categories: state.subredditSelector.get('categories'),
  subreddits: state.subredditSelector.get('subreddits')
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  setCategoryActive
})(MenuList);
```

My Category component

```
class Category extends Component {

  printToggle(active) {
    if (active) {
      return <span> [-]</span>
    } else {
      return <span> [+]</span>
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.printToggle(nextProps.active)
  }

  render() {

    const { setActive, active, name } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="category-container">
        <a onClick={setActive}
        href="#"
        className="category-title">
          {name}
          {this.printToggle(active)}
        </a>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Category
```

And my reducer

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable'
import {
  SET_SUBREDDIT_ACTIVE,
  SET_CATEGORY_ACTIVE
} from '../actions'
import List from '../data/nsfw_subreddits.js'

const initState = fromJS(List)

const subredditSelector = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_SUBREDDIT_ACTIVE:
      return state
    case SET_CATEGORY_ACTIVE:
      return state.updateIn(['categories', 'byName', action.payload.name],
        x => x.set('active', !x.get('active')))
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default subredditSelector
```

A piece of my state that I have coded as a JSON object

```
const list = {
  categories: {
    byName: {
      "example": {
        name: "example",
        id: 1,
        active: true,
        subredditsByName: ["example", "example"]
      },
      "example": {
        name: "example",
        id: 2,
        active: true,
        subredditsByName: ["example"]
      },
      "example": {
        name: "example",
        id: 3,
        active: true,
        subredditsByName: ["example", "example", "example"]
      }
    },
    allCategories: ["example", "example", "example"]
  },
  subreddits: {
```

My guess is that my reducer is mutating the state? Though I am not sure how, since I am using the immutable js functions?

Comment: Hi Albert, I just want to double check something here - Are you expecting 'My container component' to re-render AllCategories as your state changes?

If so then I think the issue here is that this.allCategories is only set once in your constructor & the reference never changes.

I'd suggest adding allCategories to your mapStateToProps method.

I'm not able to test this myself right now so I might be off the mark, but I think this approach would be worth a try!

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed this issue by changing the constructor from a constructor to a regular function and called it at the top of my render method!

Comment: A better place to update your component based on prop changes is is componentWillReceiveProps. Putting this stuff in render means it gets called more often than necessary, which might not matter for your component.

Answer (score 0):

You should still keep your constructor, but only have in it what needs to be done when the object is first created:

`constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }`

And yes, having

`cleanPropData(){
    this.categories = this.props.categories
    this.subreddits = this.props.subreddits
    this.allCategories = this.categories.get("allCategories")
    this.byName = this.categories.get("byName")
}`

is fine.  I haven't heard of someone invoking it at the top of a render function.  Nice to know that works.